# dojo : i want to change my type="dojo/connect" to "dojo/on or aspect or method"

Tags: dojo

I’m using Dojo Toolkit. Currently, I use `"dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore", dojox.grid.DataGrid, type="dojo/connect"` in my code. By the way, `dojo/connect` will be deprecated.

I’m trying to change to recent syntax (ex. "dojo/on or aspect or method". I don’t know which one I have to use), but I couldn’t fix my old code.

Here is some code. To help you understand, I summarize my code.

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore" data-dojo-id="jsonStore_3" data-dojo-props="url:'test.do?businessId=${approvalProcess.businessId}'">
    <script type="dojo/connect" data-dojo-event="onNew" data-dojo-args="newItem">
        insertApprovalNotificationHandler(this,newItem);
    </script> 
</div>

<table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
                        data-dojo-id="grid_3" id="grid_3" 
                        store="jsonStore_3" 
                        query="{ recipientName: '*' }" 
                        rowsPerPage="20" rowSelector="20px"
                        region="center"
                        style="width: 100%;">
</table>

<script>
    var test = function() {
        jsonStore_3.newItem({sample1: 'aa', sample2:'bb'});        
    }

    var insertApprovalNotificationHandler = function (object,newItem){
        console.log("TEST");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `dojox.grid.DataGrid`is deprecated. You really should use its successor `dgrid`, which usage is close to DataGrid but easier to use, with lot of advantages. You can found it with some docs at [link](http://dgrid.io/). Then you can use dgrid events (or `on()` method).

Comment: Thank you, your comment. I already head and look around dgrid and dgrid's website. But i couldn't find dgrid examples in other site, not dgrid's website. By any chance, do you know other site that having many information or examples about dgrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onNew` is a method of `dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore` not an emitted event, so you have to use `aspect`

This should be close to what you need:

```
<script type="dojo/aspect" data-dojo-advice="after" data-dojo-method="onNew" data-dojo-args="newItem">
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this method ever, but i still used 'data-dojo-event'. Your solution work very well! Thanks